# What Jar files are required for the Hadoop installation process on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: hadoop

Especially this part:

> c. Download “slf4j-1.7.21.” Copy Jar files from this folder and paste them to “C:\eclipse\plugins”.

Cannot really identify the jar files here.

Comment: which installation process are you following?

Comment: I assume the download is a zip file containing them?

Comment: Yes robin, you're right. Its a zip file. And the after extracting the zip file, it contained no zip file.

Comment: I took  this pdf online  :  Installing Hadoop-2.6.x on Windows 10. 
Shantanu Sharma Department of Computer Science, Ben-Gurion University, Israel. sharmas@cs.bgu.ac.il

Comment: I would very much love a more updated and vivid installation process, thats if there is any.

Comment: @Robin, you're right. the extracted zip file had no zip file in them

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the pdf i took online

Comment: @Washington That step is optional which is actually not necessary because hadoop itself would have slf4j libraries in its package. You can skip that step. I guess she is suggesting you to download from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21) and apply the step.